# Кто придумывает сленговые слова и выражения?

Tags: жаргон

**К сленгу принято относиться негативно,** практически не отличая сленговые выражения от неграмотной речи.

Но это другая тема, меня же интересует вот что:  **как придумывают сленговые слова и чем они отличаются от индивидуально-авторских неологизмов?**

**Мне кажется, что придумать сленговое слово не так просто.** К примеру, авторские неологизмы обычно так и остаются в  книгах автора, а сленговое слово должно укрепиться "в массах", получить одобрение, завоевать доверие.

Человек, способный к словотворчеству такого вида, должен обладать наблюдательностью, чувством вкуса, иронией, языковым чутьем, иначе вряд ли можно сочинить что-либо достойное внимания.

Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Тут действует теория больших чисел. Миллионы дилетантов придумают слов гораздо больше, чем сотни профессионалов и то, что большинство из этих слов никогда не уйдет дальше круга друзей не означает, что какое-нибудь из них не прорвется в массы.

Мне самому доводилось придумывать новые слова, *паузируй ( поставь на паузу), матаковать (играть на прямой мат в шахматах), контр-игрушка (слабая контр-игра)* и пр. При этом потом встречать их в том же значении у других людей никак со мной не связанных. Мысли людей сходятся.

Answer (score 0):

Не ошибаетесь. Жаргон, сленг - иностранные слова. В русском языке не знали что ли о такой особенности речи? Знали, конечно. И называли это правильно, точно. Но знатоки не понимали точно русского слова. И что случилось? Это точное слово стало восприниматься иначе, а иностранные слова, типа "жаргон" и "сленг" заняли его место. 
Всего-то вернуть слово "словеса" в его ипостась.

Comment: "Словеса" - о другом (не об отдельных словах): о пустословии, многослословии или  бессодержательности речи. Так было и во времена Даля. Вам известно какое-то более старое значение "словес"?